# Torques on a spinning soccer ball

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, angular-velocity

I have a project in university.
it is a simulation of soccer kick so I created all the forces like magnus and drag and friction and gravity and so on.. now the ball is moving and has  a linear velocity and angular velocity. I know that the linear velocity will decrease because of the friction, but how the angular velocity will decrease.
what torques effect the ball while it is moving and spinning.

Comment: a lot of people seem to have a similar project recently...

Comment: @JohnHunter Oh I wasn't aware of this. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: It could be worth a search of recent questions with "ball" or "soccer" in them

Comment: @noah , sorry thought you were the questioner, it's up to you after you've searched, perhaps you will know what's best...

Comment: @JohnHunter I have only found two related questions in relatively recent time, both asking for differet concepts and both asked by the same user. I'll leave the answer here but will holf off on elaborating on exact calculations in case this is some kind of problem sheet.

Comment: That's fine, there were three with the search "soccer" from within about 10 days before...all the best.

Answer (score 1):

It's really very much the same as for linear velocity, i.e. friction with the air. Since the frictional force opposes the velocity of the surface, a spinning ball experiences a torque opposing its rotation from its surface rubbing against the air around it.

Comment: thank you for answering . how can i calulate the torque exactly

Comment: the magnus effect comes from this torque (the fact that air resistance is greater on one side of th ball than the other). look up forces in the mangus effect and that should help get you in the right direction @ahmadalseirafi